# FritzBox 7530 Wireguard: No such Host known

Tags: dns, wireguard

recently I set up WireGuard on my FritzBox 7530 after it updated to FritzOS 07.50.
Everything is working perfectly fine except one thing.
When I am at my girlfriends place (she has a FritzBox Fon WLAN 7390), I can't turn on the WireGuard connection.
Whenever I try to connect, I get the Error-Message `no such host is known`.

Here is my .config file:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXXXX
Address = 192.168.10.202/24
DNS = 192.168.10.1, fritz.box

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
PresharedKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AllowedIPs = 192.168.10.0/24, 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.myfritz.net:51569
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

And the log:

```
2023-01-20 22:29:19.876766: [TUN] [wg_config_win11] Starting WireGuard/0.5.3 (Windows 10.0.22621; amd64)
2023-01-20 22:29:19.876766: [TUN] [wg_config_win11] Watching network interfaces
2023-01-20 22:29:19.879436: [TUN] [wg_config_win11] Resolving DNS names
2023-01-20 22:29:19.926975: [TUN] [wg_config_win11] Unable to resolve one or more DNS hostname endpoints: No such host is known.
2023-01-20 22:29:19.927566: [TUN] [wg_config_win11] Shutting down
2023-01-20 22:29:19.929160: [MGR] [wg_config_win11] Tunnel service tracker finished
```

Result of `ipconfig` at my girlfriends place:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fritz.box
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5e1f:e3f0:573d:fde4%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.91
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
And maybe with an explanation why this problem occurs? I am pretty new to all this stuff and am still trying to find my way around.
Thank you :)

If this is the wrong forum, can someone tell me which the right one is? (I asked on StackOverflow before)

**Edit 1:**
I think I know what the problem is. As I am connected to a FritzBox the DNS Server (default settings from provider) is not redirecting the endpoint `XXXXX.myfritz.net` outside of the local network.
Since the "name" of my Fritzbox is not known in the local network of my girlfriends Fritzbox, it can't connect.

Is there a way to "force" the Fritzbox to redirect the endpoint outside of the local network?

Comment: The number 1 pointless setting is `DNS = fritz.box`. Remove it. This will also result in only one DNS name remaining in the config, making the error message unambiguous.

Comment: @DanielB I tried that, but the problem still persisted with the same error message.

Comment: Alright. Then you can use `nslookup` or a similar tool to check whether the DNS name works. Also use websites on the net to check. `myfritz.net` is a DDNS service operated by AVM, so long as your FritzBox has it activated, it should work anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I used `nslookup` and got an ipv6 adress back for `XXXXX.myfritz.net`. Wether I was connected via Fritzbox or via Hotspot+VPN, I got the same ipv6 adress back. If I search in the browser, I get redirected to MyFrizt via Hotspot+VPN, but if I am connected to her FritzBox, I get nothing.

Comment: Does your girlfriend have IPv6 internet? Do _you_ perhaps have Dual Stack Lite (DS-Lite)?

Comment: We both habe DS-Lite as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments and your question, I arrive at the following conclusions:

- Your home internet connection is either “Dual Stack Lite” (AKA DS-Lite, where you have a public IPv6 address and are behind carrier-grade NAT on IPv4), or, however unlikely, IPv6-only
- Your girlfriend’s home internet connection does not have IPv6 at all (no global address in `ipconfig` output, it would be above the *Link-local IPv6 Address* line)
- Your `myfritz.net` dynamic DNS domain is working fine and shows the only public address you have, the IPv6 address

I’m not entirely sure about what exactly you mean by “Hotspot+VPN”, but that’s just a minor problem.

You cannot directly connect from IPv4 to IPv6 endpoints or vice versa.

If you want your home VPN to be reachable from the IPv4 internet, you need to host it elsewhere. One option would be to use an inexpensive virtual private server (or any server, really) that both your home network and your mobile devices would connect to. Another option is to use a service like ZeroTier or Tailscale. Their unique selling point is that everything just works(tm), regardless of firewalls, NAT, IPv4, IPv6 and whatnot.

---

As an example, this is how `ipconfig` looks like with global IPv6 connectivity:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : w23.lan
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:e90c:e67:206b:d84e
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:785f:eb5f:dd1b:b053
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c5d4:c6d9:53ab:1caa%7
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.21
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::ce2d:e0ff:fe07:1a8a%7
                                       192.168.2.1
```